# How do I do multiple assignment in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, variables, variable-assignment

Here's an example of what I'm looking for:

```
>> foo = [88, 12];
>> [x, y] = foo;
```

I'd *expect* something like this afterwards:

```
>> x

x =

    88

>> y

y =

    12
```

But instead I get errors like:

```
??? Too many output arguments.
```

I thought `deal()` might do it, but it seems to only work on cells.

```
>> [x, y] = deal(foo{:});
??? Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.
```

How do I solve my problem?  Must I constantly index by 1 and 2 if I want to deal with them separately?

Comment: Deal works only if foo is a cell. You have defined foo as a standard array. That's why you got the `??? Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.` error message.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You don't need `deal` at all (edit: for Matlab 7.0 or later) and, for your example, you don't need `mat2cell`; you can use `num2cell` with no other arguments::

```
foo = [88, 12];
fooCell = num2cell(foo);
[x y]=fooCell{:}

x =

    88


y =

    12
```

If you want to use `deal` for some other reason, you can:

```
foo = [88, 12];
fooCell = num2cell(foo);
[x y]=deal(fooCell{:})

x =

    88


y =

    12
```

Comment: Just a side note, I think you can only get away with not using deal( as in the first example) in Matlab 7+.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know that deal is unnecessary nowadays. 

However, I used mat2cell on purpose, since I assume that the OP might want to separate columns from each other.

Comment: This is really good.  But is there any way to have it all on one line?  Maybe something like: `[x y] = num2cell(foo){:}`  (Sorry, still confused by Matlab quite often.)

Comment: @Justin: good point, you need version 7.0 (2004) or later. @Jonas: true, `mat2cell` is good if you want to split up in different ways. @Benjamin: I'm not aware of a one line method, unless you use a cell to begin with; you can use `deal(88,12)` if you are starting from scalars. It'd be good if we stuff like `num2cell(foo){:}` for many Matlab commands.

Answer (score 19):

Note that [`deal`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/deal.html) accepts a "list" as argument, not a cell array. So the following works as expected:

```
> [x,y] = deal(88,12)
x = 88

y = 12
```

The syntax `c{:}` transforms a cell array in a list, and a list is a [comma separated values](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br2js35-1.html), like in function arguments. Meaning that you can use the `c{:}` syntax as argument to other functions than `deal`. To see that, try the following:

```
> z = plus(1,2)
z = 3

> c = {1,2};
> z = plus(c{:});
z = 3
```

Answer (score 8):

To use the `num2cell` solution in one line, define a helper function `list`:

```
function varargout = list(x)
% return matrix elements as separate output arguments
% example: [a1,a2,a3,a4] = list(1:4)

varargout = num2cell(x);

end
```

Comment: won't the example `[a1,a2,a3,a4] = list(1:4)` cause `Too many output arguments` error?

Answer (score 4):

What [mtrw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337126/multiple-assignment-in-matlab/2337218#2337218) said. Basically, you want to use deal with a cell array (though deal(88,12) works as well).

Assuming you start with an array foo that is n-by-2, and you want to assign the first column to x and the second to y, you do the following:

```
foo = [88,12;89,13;90,14];
%# divide the columns of foo into separate cells, i.e. do mat2cell(foo,3,[1,1])
fooCell = mat2cell(foo,size(foo,1),ones(size(foo,2),1));
[x,y] = deal(fooCell{:});
```

Answer (score 3):

[DEAL](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/deal.html) is really useful, and really confusing.  `foo` needs to be a cell array itself, I believe.  The following seems to work in Octave, if I remember correctly it will work in MATLAB as well:

```
> foo = {88, 12}
foo =

{
  [1,1] =  88
  [1,2] =  12
}

> [x,y] = deal(foo{:})
x =  88
y =  12
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment other answers, so separate addition.

> [you can use deal(88,12) if you are starting from scalars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337126/how-do-i-do-multiple-assignment-in-matlab#comment2309846_2337336)

`deal` can be used as a one-liner for non-scalars as well, of course if you already have them in separate variables, say:

```
a = 123;
b = rand(3);
c = {a, b};
d = struct('field','val')
```

and now you deal them with one line:

```
>> [x,y,z,w] = deal(a,b,c,d)
x =
   123
y =
    0.6370    0.2165    0.6711
    0.2945    0.8803    0.2705
    0.7633    0.1537    0.0767
z = 
    [123]    [3x3 double]
w = 
    field: 'val'
```

However, if they are packed in one variable, you can only `deal` them if they are in a cell or structure array - with `deal(X{:})` for cell array and `deal(S.field)` for structure array. (In the latter case only one field is dealt, but from all structures in array.) With Matlab v.7+ you can use `X{:}` and `S.field` without `deal`, as noted in other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function arr2vars for convenience

```
function varargout = arr2vars(arr)
% Distribute elements over variables

N = numel(arr);
if nargout ~= N
    error('Number of outputs does not match number of elements')
end
for k = 1:N
    varargout{k} = arr(k);
end
```

You can use it then like this

```
[~,roi] = imcrop(im);
[x,w,y,h] = arr2vars(roi);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for

```
>>> foo = [88, 12];
>>> [x, y] = deal(foo(1), foo(2))
```

resulting in

```
x = 
    88

y = 
    12
```

So you have a working one-liner.

Answer (score -1):

There is an easier way.

```
x = foo (1, 1)  
y = foo (1, 2)
```

Provides

```
>> x

x =

88

>> y

y =

12
```

Full documentation at [Mathworks.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stateflow/ug/assign-and-access-vector-and-matrix-values.html)