# Is there anything like deal() for normal MATLAB arrays?

Tags: arrays, matlab, variables, variable-assignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I do multiple assignment in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337126/how-do-i-do-multiple-assignment-in-matlab)

When dealing with cell arrays, I can use the `deal()` function to assign cells to output variables, such as:

```
[a, b, c] = deal(myCell{:});
```

or just:

```
[a, b, c] = myCell{:};
```

I would like to do the same thing for a simple array, such as:

```
myArray = [1, 2, 3];
[a, b, c] = deal(myArray(:));
```

But this doesn't work. What's the alternative?

Comment: I thought this question sounded familiar, but it took me some time to find the duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337126/multiple-assignment-in-matlab. I think I'll try to tag these questions better when I get a chance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One option is to convert your array to a cell array first using [NUM2CELL](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/num2cell.html):

```
myArray = [1, 2, 3];
cArray = num2cell(myArray);
[a, b, c] = cArray{:};
```

As you note, you don't even need to use [DEAL](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/deal.html) to distribute the cell contents.

Comment: Isn't this a one-liner?  `[a,b,c] = num2cell(myArray){:}`

Comment: @mtrw: Nope, that throws this error: `??? Error: ()-indexing must appear last in an index expression.`

Comment: Oh interesting.  It works in Octave.  I guess the FOSS version can't afford to buy a temp variable.

Answer (score 0):

Not terribly pretty, but:

```
myArray = 1:3;
c = arrayfun(@(x) x, myArray , 'UniformOutput', false); 
c{:}
```

Comment: Actually, scratch that, the `arrayfun` call basically does the same thing as `num2cell`.

Comment: Here's a trick for shorter array/cell/Xfun calls: instead of 'UniformOutput',false, you can just have your anonymous function return a cell. c = arrayfun(@(x) {x}, myArray)