# MATLAB Easiest way to assign elements of a vector to individual variables

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I do multiple assignment in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337126/how-do-i-do-multiple-assignment-in-matlab)

So let's say I have a vector `p = [1 2 3]`. I want a command that looks like this:

```
[x y z] = p;
```

so that x = p(1), y = p(2), and z = p(3).

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740704/is-there-anything-like-deal-for-normal-matlab-arrays, which is itself a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337126/multiple-assignment-in-matlab

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Convert to cell array.

```
pCell = num2cell(p);
[x,y,z] = pCell{:};
```

Comment: Well, looks like this is the best I can do.

Comment: Why defining pCell at all:
[x,y,z] = num2cell(p){:};

Comment: @Philipp: In which version of Matlab can you do that? Octave has the feature, but Matlab doesn't have it (yet)

Comment: @Jonas You are so right. I am currently only using octave and I am not aware of the small differences.

Comment: @Philipp: No problem. Agreed that chain-indexing would really be nice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`deal`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/deal.html):

`[x y z] = deal( p(1), p(2), p(3) )`

Comment: Well, that's just as verbose as `x = p(1); y = p(2), z = p(3)`

Answer (score 2):

Well, turns out there's no way to one-line this, so I wrote a function.

```
function varargout = deal_array(arr)
    s = numel(arr);
    n = nargout;

    if n > s
        error('Insufficient number of elements in array!');
    elseif n == 0
        return;
    end

    for i = 1:n
        varargout(i) = {arr(i)}; %#ok<AGROW>
    end
end
```