# Octave basics: How to assign variables from a vector

Tags: octave

Maybe I'm spoiled by Python, but does Octave allows one to assign the values of variables directly from a vector? That is, doing something like

```
a,b,c=[5,6,7]
```

will result with `a=5, b=6, c=7`.
I have tried many combinations of writing the expression above, but no luck yet ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done by constructing a cell array with "{...}" and converting this to a comma separated list via "{:}":

```
[a b c] = {5 6 7}{:}
a =  5
b =  6
c =  7
```

Comment: spiffy, just to complete the picture, here's how to do that starting from a vector: mat2cell([5 6 7], 1, [1, 1, 1]){:}

Comment: is it really the best way to do this in octave ??

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work when you actually have a vector to deal with:

```
v = [5, 6, 7];
[a, b, c] = num2cell(v){:}
```

(Extracted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2893408) Matlab answer.)

Answer (score 0):

`deal()` is meant for this task, for separate input values:

```
>> [a,b,c] = deal(5,6,7)
a = 5
b = 6
c = 7
```