# How to do multivariable assignment in octave?

Tags: matlab, syntax, octave

I want to do multivariable assignment. I can do `[a,b] = min([1 2 3])` but I can't do `[a,b] = [1,2]`. Why? Is there any workaround?

Comment: Examples in this PAQ

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908398/octave-basics-how-to-assign-variables-from-a-vector

Comment: Please consider removing the Matlab tag since the accepted answer won't work there. My answer using `deal` would do the job in Octave and Matlab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[1,2]` on the right hand side of the assignment is interpreted as array with the two elements `1` and `2`.

If you want to do the multi-variable-assignment in one line, you can use `deal` in Matlab. This should work in Octave as well according to the documentation [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Variable_002dlength-Return-Lists.html).

```
>> [a,b] = deal(1,2)
a =
     1
b =
     2
```

The advantage of using `deal` is that it works in Matlab as well, where the solution with `[a b] = {1 2}{:}` won't.

Answer (score 2):

[Octave basics: How to assign variables from a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908398/octave-basics-how-to-assign-variables-from-a-vector)

```
>> [a b c] = {5 6 7}{:}
a =  5
b =  6
c =  7
```

Answer (score 0):

To adapt Cobusve's answer to Matlab, two lines are required:

```
>> h={5 6 7}

h = 

    [5]    [6]    [7]

>> [a b c]=h{:}

a =

     5


b =

     6


c =

     7
```