# How do I extract matrix elements in matlab?

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [MATLAB Easiest way to assign elements of a vector to individual variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893356/matlab-easiest-way-to-assign-elements-of-a-vector-to-individual-variables)
>   [How do I do multiple assignment in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337126/how-do-i-do-multiple-assignment-in-matlab)

If I have a matrix: `A = [1, 5, 10]`, do I set `a1 = A(1), b1 = B(1)`, etc. on one line? I want to do something like:

```
[a1 a2 a3] = Blah(A)
```

Comment: this question has been asked before multiple times: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337126/how-do-i-do-multiple-assignment-in-matlab , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893356/matlab-easiest-way-to-assign-elements-of-a-vector-to-individual-variables , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740704/is-there-anything-like-deal-for-normal-matlab-arrays

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the answers you can find in all the questions I linked to, here's yet another one-liner inspired by this [@gnovice post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/matlab-array-index-without-assigning-to-a-local-variable/3628885#3628885) using SUBSREF:

```
>> A = [1 5 10];
>> [x y z] = subsref(num2cell(A), struct('type','{}','subs',{{':'}}))
x =
     1
y =
     5
z =
    10
```

Basically its equivalent to: `[x y z] = num2cell(A){:}` (but thats non-valid syntax)