# Pulling values out of a vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How do I do multiple assignment in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337126/how-do-i-do-multiple-assignment-in-matlab)
>   [Is there anything like deal() for normal MATLAB arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740704/is-there-anything-like-deal-for-normal-matlab-arrays)

I want to put values of a vector in 2 variables, but it doesn't work.

```
vec = [2 3];
[m n] = vec;
```

I expected:

> m = 2
>
> n = 3

But I got an error.

It's a syntax problem or I can't do that?

Comment: in short: you can do it, but not like that.

Comment: And a couple more duplicates (this seems to be a fairly common question): [Is there anything like deal() for normal MATLAB arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740704/is-there-anything-like-deal-for-normal-matlab-arrays), [MATLAB Easiest way to assign elements of a vector to individual variables.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893356/matlab-easiest-way-to-assign-elements-of-a-vector-to-individual-variables).

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to assign values of a vector to different variables, but you cannot do it like that.

Easy way:

```
vec = [ 2 3 ];
m = vec(1);
n = vec(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another variation using an anonymous function.

```
vec = [2 3];
tuple = @(x) deal(x(1), x(2))
[m n] = tuple(vec)
```

Comment: While this is correct, this is probably way to advanced for the OP.  I suspect this is more of a "How do I index into a matrix?" question.