# Matlab - Dealing values to variables in one line

Tags: matlab, variables, vector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I do multiple assignment in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337126/how-do-i-do-multiple-assignment-in-matlab)

Say I have vector of values, `v = 1:3`, 

 and I want to assign the vector values to variables so `a=1, b=2, c=3`.

 Trying to do so with `[a, b, c] = deal(v)` results with `a=b=c=[1 2 3]`.

Does anyone know any one-liner for doing so, other than the obvious `a=v(1), b=v(2), c=v(3)`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740704/is-there-anything-like-deal-for-normal-matlab-arrays and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337126/how-do-i-do-multiple-assignment-in-matlab

Comment: I dare say this may be the most oft-duplicated MATLAB question on SO. Here are some more duplicates: [MATLAB Easiest way to assign elements of a vector to individual variables.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893356/matlab-easiest-way-to-assign-elements-of-a-vector-to-individual-variables-close), [How do I extract matrix elements in matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743586/how-do-i-extract-matrix-elements-in-matlab-closed), [Pulling values out of a vector in MATLAB.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672215/pulling-values-out-of-a-vector-in-matlab-closed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite a one-liner,  but close.

```
% Convert v to be a cell array, with each element in a different cell.
v = 1:3;
v2 = arrayfun(@(x) x, v, 'UniformOutput', false)

% Assign each cell to a different variable
[a, b, c] = v2{:}
```

Comment: You can just write `v2=num2cell(v)` for the same effect. See also the answers to the linked duplicate questions.

Answer (score 1):

Not a one-liner (I'm sure there is one out there!), but here's a function you could add to your MATLAB path that seems to do the right sort of thing:

```
function varargout  = deal2 ( inputVec ) 

for i = 1:nargout
    varargout{i} = inputVec(i);
end

end
```

Using this:

```
>> [a, b, c] = deal2([1 200 10])

a =

 1


b =

200


c =

10
```

This will work for any length input vector and number of outputs, provided the number of outputs is less than or equal to the length of the input vector.