# Matlab multiple variable assignments

Tags: matlab

I would like to assign the values in a vector of length 2 to multiple variables.  The output of size() is able to do this:

```
% works
[m,n] = size([0 0]);
```

However splitting this into two lines doesn't work:

```
sz = size([0 0]);
[m,n] = sz;
% returns:
%   ??? Too many output arguments.
```

What is special about the return value of size that is lost when it is assigned to a variable?

Comment: Have a look at [`varargout`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargout.html?refresh=true) and also at [`nargout`](https://nf.nci.org.au/facilities/software/Matlab/techdoc/ref/nargin.html)

Comment: `size()` is a function. So when you do `size([0 0])`, it goes inside the internal function and returns two arguments. In the second case, `sz` is a variable which is a vector of length 2. Now you are trying to assign a single variable to two variables. That won't happen. You can write your own function to do that.

Comment: look here for multiple variable assignments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740704/is-there-anything-like-deal-for-normal-matlab-arrays

Comment: Thanks Parag S. Chandakkar I decided to write my own function to handle arbitrary length vectors

Comment: Wow Dan, I wish I had known about varargout before I wrote that silly eval() business

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The custom function you introduced is quite an overkill and uses functions like `eval` which are considered bad practice. It can be done much shorter. That's all you need:

```
function [ varargout ] = split( Vector )

varargout = num2cell( Vector );

end
```

And because of [**`varargout`**](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/varargout.html) you have a variable-length output argument list and you don't need to edit your function for more argements.

It works for vectors as well as for matrices:

```
[a,b,c,d] = split( [1,2;3,4] )

a =  1

b =  3

c =  2

d =  4
```

If you don't like the matrix compatibility, include a condition and check the dimensions of the input vector.

Comment: The first sentence alone deserves a +1. Using `varargout` is the smoothest way to do this. There's also an approach using anonymous function that doesn't require a separate script (see my answer). Unless you introduce some nargin, nargout checks, this solution will have the same pitfalls as mine. The difference is: You can introduce such tests, while it's impossible using just an anonymous function.

Comment: @RobertP. I thought about the deal solution as well. But the OP obviously just used `size` as an example and actually needs to split more values. Its harder with `deal` then.

Comment: I agree my function is way overkill

Answer (score 4):

Matlab's output arguments are interesting this way. A function can have a variable number of outputs depending on how many the ‘user’ asked for.

When you write

```
[m,n] = size([0 0]);
```

you are requesting two output arguments. Inside the function itself this would correspond to the variable `nargout` equal to `2`.

But when you write

```
sz = size([0 0]);
```

the `size` function recognises that it's a single output argument, and gives you both `m` and `n` as a vector instead of two singleton outputs.
This style of behaviour is (I think) generally uncommon in Matlab.

Also note that Matlab doesn't allow multiple arguments to break up vectors:

```
x = [1 1]
[y,z] = x
```

returns `Too many output arguments.`

Answer (score 3):

If you for some reason don't want to have this in a separate function, you can have an anonymous function return multiple outputs like this:

```
split = @(x) deal(x(1), x(2))
A = zeros(5,3)
sz = size(A)

[x, y] = split(sz)
   x =  5
   y =  3
```

The `deal` function sees two left side arguments and thus produce the correct output. Note that this function will not respond well to wrong input and output. Check out [Loren's blog](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/01/31/multiple-outputs/) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it transforming `sz` to a cell array, and then generating a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) from that array:

```
sz_cell = mat2cell(sz(:), ones(numel(sz),1));
[m, n] = sz_cell{:}; %// Or [m, n] = deal(sz_cell{:});
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't something special about the size value.It is just that it deals with sz as a single argument since you are copying to it the result of size and that's why it can't have 2 outputs.

You will get the same error by using any other function which defined by 1 output , for example : [m,n] = cos(0)  etc..

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do this.  Thanks to Will Robertson's answer I realized that writing a function was the only way to really get what I want.  Here is split.

```
function [ o1, o2, o3, o4, o5, o6, o7, o8 ] = split( v )
%SPLIT Splits a vector of bounded length into individual return variables.
% Split() can handle arbitrarily long input vectors, but only a fixed
% number of output variables.  @benathon
%
% Usage:
%  vec = [1 2 3 4 5];
%  [a,b,c,d,e] = split(vec);
%  [f,g]       = split(vec);

% If you would like to upgrade split() to handle more output variables,
% simply add more output variables to the function definition and
% then change this variable
maxout = 8;

[~,n] = size(v);

if n < nargout
    error('input vector too short for number of output arguments');
end

% we only need to assign this many output variables
iterations = min(n,nargout);


% Matlab catches "Too many output arguments." before we can
%if( iterations > maxout )
%    error('Too many output, edit split.m to easily upgrade');
%end


i = 1;
while i <= iterations
    expression = sprintf('o%d=v(%d);', i, i);
    eval(expression);
    i = i + 1;
end
```

Look in the comments for usage.  I've also made a gist: https://gist.github.com/esromneb/652fed46ae328b17e104