# Declare & initialize variables in one line in MATLAB without using an array or vector

Tags: matlab

```
a = 0;
b = 0;
c = 0;
```

Can I do this in one statement without using an array/vecor?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would try using the `deal` function.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html

```
      [a,b,c] = deal(0,0,0);
```

There are other ways, but this is a good function to learn.

Comment: You can also do `[a,b,c] = deal(0);` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5158206/3599179).