# Distribute elements of an array to different variables in Matlab

Tags: list, matlab, variables, vector, aesthetics

I see equivalent operations being done several times in my Matlab code, and I think, there must be a way to condense these and do it all once.
In this case it was checking whether some variables were less than a certain epsilon:

```
if abs(beta) < tol
    beta = 0;
end
if abs(alpha) < tol
    alpha = 0;
end
if abs(gamma) < tol
    gamma = 0;
end
```

I tried combining these into a few lines that deal with the whole boodle,

```
overTol = [alpha,beta,gamma] >= tol;
[alpha,beta,gamma] = [alpha,beta,gamma] .* overTol;
```

If this was Python, where a list is a list is a list, that would be fine, but in Matlab, an operation on the right produces one variable on the left except in special situations.

After reading [Define multiple variables at the same time in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158032/define-multiple-variables-at-the-same-time-in-matlab?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [Declare & initialize variables in one line in MATLAB without using an array or vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575027/declare-initialize-variables-in-one-line-in-matlab-without-using-an-array-or-v), I tried using `deal`, but `[alpha,beta,gamma] = deal([alpha,beta,gamma] .* overTol);` does not distribute the terms of the vector given to the deal function between the terms in the vector on the left, but instead gives a copy of the whole vector to each of the terms.

The last thing I want to do is set the right equal to a unique vector and then set alpha, beta, and gamma equal to the terms of that vector, one by one. That's just as ugly as what I started with.

Is there an elegant solution to this?

Comment: With `deal` you still need to explicitly repeat the operation on the right: `[alpha, beta] = deal(alpha.*(abs(alpha)>=tol), beta.*(abs(beta)>=tol));` You could define an anonymous function `f = @(x) x.*abs(x)>=x;` and then `alpha = f(alpha); beta = f(beta); gamma= f(gamma)`. To produce the most compact code you should collect the three variables into a single one (N-dim array or cell array). Would that be an option?

Comment: MATLAB does not split arrays into variables easily because MATLAB is designed to work with the arrays themselves, not with scalar values. There are tricks you could use, but I wouldn’t want to maintain code that uses these tricks. What is the problem with repeating a statement three times for three different variables?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/2337126/7328782

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes, I ended up putting ```alpha```, ```beta```, and ```gamma``` together into ```alpha_beta_gamma```, which worked because they ended up serving as components of the same array and nothing else. 
But what if I need to run each through several operations? Well, in that case I think @CrisLuengo's reference might help a whole lot, though I'm not sure at the moment if it goes the whole way.

Comment: @Post169 What operations do you anticipate running your values through? In this case you've reduced your 3 `if` clauses to `alpha_beta_gamma(abs(alpha_beta_gamma)<tol) = 0;`

Comment: @Post169 Once you have the three variables in an array, that should make it easier to apply _any_ common operation to all of them... What operations are thinking of? Can you give a specific example?

Comment: The fact of the matter is, I don't need to do any further operations, but just set a row of a matrix equal to ```alpha_beta_gamma```. Thank you all, @LuisMendo, @CrisLuengo, and @beaker, for your comments! I hope this is helpful for others, even though I didn't accept an actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the comments explain why there are probably better approaches. I was curious if it could be done. It can, but maybe it shouldn't be.

```
% Initial values
a = 0.01; b = 0.1; c = 1; 
% Tolerance
tol = 0.05;
% Function - note returns a scalar cell
f = @(f) {f.*(abs(f)>tol)}
% arrayfun returns a cell of the new values
% cell2struct turns that into a struct array with a single field 'f'
% the trailing dot-reference extracts that field and builds a 
% comma-separated list which can be used to assign the new values
[a2,b2,c2] =  cell2struct(arrayfun(f, [a,b,c]),{'f'}).f
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `cellfun` to generate a cell array of results, and `deal` to redistribute it back into variables

```
f = @(x) x.*(abs(x)>tol);             % function which returns x, or x if abs(x)<tol
d = cellfun( f, {a,b,c}, 'uni', 0 );  % apply function to inputs a,b,c
[a,b,c] = deal(d{:});                 % deal results back to a,b,c
```

A more readable (and maintenance-friendly) method might be to just use functions and accept that it's going to use more lines. Line count is not the enemy...

```
a = applyTol(a);
b = applyTol(b);
c = applyTol(c);

function x = applyTol( x )
    tol = 0.5;
    if abs(x) < tol
        x = 0;
    end
end
```