# 'Safe' Assignment in MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab

I've noticed that in a python code you can do something like:

```
a=0
b=1
a,b=b,a
print(a,b)
```

which outputs (a=1,b=0) (i.e. each variable is assigned independently of the last assignment). Is there a way to do something similar in MATLAB?

Sorry if this is a really simple question, but I've been trying to find a clean answer to this for a bit of time now and haven't found anything.

Comment: Actually, this is a possible duplicate of [How do I do multiple assignment in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337126/how-do-i-do-multiple-assignment-in-matlab) and [Define multiple variables at the same time in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158032/define-multiple-variables-at-the-same-time-in-matlab).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need for an additional temporary variable here. If you want multiple assignments in a single statement, you can use [`deal`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html):

```
[a, b] = deal(b, a)
```

I believe this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you actually this is perfect.

Comment: Woaw, almost as pretty as in Python, nice :p

Comment: What is the overhead of `deal` vs. just creating a temporary variable? The JIT can easily optimize away a temporary variable. Even though `deal` is not particularly complicated internally, I wonder if it's a good idea to use it when performance matters?

Comment: @horchler JIT acceleration is something fairly hard to predict (at least for me). While it can be tested, I think you're overcomplicating the question.

Comment: That's true if the code is overly complicated. But for simple cases of directly switching the contents of variables with a temporary variable it might be good. A test on my machine (R2013a, OS X) show that `deal` was *12 times slower* than using a temporary variable. This was constant across a wide range range of variable sizes. Convenience often has a cost.

Answer (score 2):

It's always possible to do that with a temporary variable in any language. The unpacking method of Python is just a little syntax sugar to simplify the developer life :)

```
a = 0
b = 1
tmp = a
a = b
b = tmp
print(a,b)
```

Anyway, it's not magical, the Python byte code might implement the permutation with a temporary variable. (There's techniques to do this without temp variable, but well... for the sake of clarity use one :p)

Comment: yeah I should have thought of that... I guess I was too caught up with how pretty it looked in python. Forgive my novice skills :P