# How can I unpack a Matlab structure into function arguments?

Tags: matlab

Using a combination of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390766/matlab-accessing-an-element-of-a-multidimensional-array-with-a-list) and [this Mathworks help thing on comma sep. lists](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html?s_tid=doc_12b#br2js35-13) I came up with this ugly way to make my formatting arguments a little prettier:

```
formatting{1,1} = 'color';      formatting{2,1} = 'black';
formatting{1,2} = 'fontweight'; formatting{2,2} = 'bold';
formatting{1,3} = 'fontsize';   formatting{2,3} = 24;

xlabel('Distance', formatting{:});
```

But it's still kinda ugly...is there a way to unpack a structure into a bunch of arguments a la a Python dictionary to `**kwargs`?

For instance, if I had the (IMHO) cleaner structure:

```
formatting = struct()
formatting.color = 'black';
formatting.fontweight = 'bold';
formatting.fontsize = 24;
```

Can I just pass that in somehow?  If I try directly (`xlabel('blah', formatting)`, or `formatting{:}`, it craps out saying "Wrong number of arguments".

Answer (score 8):

You are very close. Just switch to a 1-D cell array.

```
formatting = {'Color', 'Red', 'LineWidth', 10};
figure
plot(rand(1,10), formatting{:})
```

If you really want to use a struct for formatting arguments, you can unpack it to a cell array and use it like above.

```
formattingStruct = struct();
formattingStruct.color = 'black';
formattingStruct.fontweight = 'bold';
formattingStruct.fontsize = 24;

fn = fieldnames(formattingStruct);
formattingCell = {};
for i = 1:length(fn)
    formattingCell = {formattingCell{:}, fn{i}, formattingStruct.(fn{i})};
end

plot(rand(1,10), formatting{:})
```

It's probably a good idea to do the struct unpacking a separate little function so you can reuse it easily.

Answer (score 7):

You can convert your structure to cell array with this function:

```
function c = struct2opt(s)

fname = fieldnames(s);
fval = struct2cell(s);
c = [fname, fval]';
c = c(:);
```

Then

```
formatting = struct2opt(formattingStructure);
xlabel('Distance', formatting{:});
```