# Prepping the number of inputs for a function in MATLAB

Tags: function, matlab, input

For example, [`ndgrid`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) has inputs as n vectors where `n` is decided by the user.

For my use case, `n` can change. I would like to prepare the input list before hand, based on `n`, then feed the inputs to `ndgrid`. How do I do that please?

For example, say I have 3 row vectors `x1`, `x2`, and `x3`. Then, if `n=3` and I put `inputs = [x1,x2,x3]`, and I use `ndgrid(inputs)` then MATLAB treats this as `ndgrid([x1,x2,x3])` instead of `ndgrid(x1,x2,x3)`. I want the latter, not the former. How do I solve this please?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598085/split-a-list-into-several-variables-in-matlab. 'deal' function may helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we use a cell array, for example `x = {some,stuff,inside}` you can unpack the cell with `x{:}`, in a function call, each elements of the cell will be passed as an argument: `myfunction(x{:})` is equivalent to `myfunction(some, stuff, inside)`.

In your case:

```
% Number of inputs
k = 3;
% Put your k input in a cell array
x = {1:3,1:3,1:3};
% If needed you can also have a dynamic output variable
X = cell(k,1);
% Get the result
[X{:}] = ndgrid(x{:})
```

Comment: Elegant simplicity. This is exactly what I needed.