# how to compare array with matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I would like to comapre two arrays of strings 
how could I affect the following values to `a`,`b`,`c`,`d` , when I try as below, I got an error

```
[a,b,c,d] = getVal(x);
    =>this will gives :
a =

a
b=

0
c =

10
d =
[]
```

and I have :

```
expected = {'a','0','10',[]};
```

how could I make the comparison between [a,b,c,d] and expected ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I do multiple assignment in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337126/how-do-i-do-multiple-assignment-in-matlab)

Comment: I've updated my question by ginving values

Answer (score 2):

*Mistake 1*:

`=` is the assignment operator.

The comparison operator is `==`.

---

*Mistake 2*:

MATLAB arrays don't generally hold strings. They hold *numbers* or single characters.

```
>> b = ['a','0','10','20']

b =

a01020
```

To see why `[a,b,c,d] = ['a','0','10','20']` doesn't work, consider this:

```
>> [a,b,c,d] = 'a01020'
??? Too many output arguments.
```

You're trying to put six characters into four buckets. Not going to work.

You might have meant to create a cell array:

```
>> c = {'a','0','10','20'}

c = 

    'a'    '0'    '10'    '20'
```

---

Matlab arrays are *numerical matrices*, not general-purpose list containers.

Comment: what I want to do is to affect each string to a value from table

Comment: @lola - Can you post the exact text of the error you are getting? Also, if you want to show values in a column rather than a row, then do c' (the apostrophe ' means transpose)

Answer (score 2):

Following on from Li-aung's answer, what you probably want is something like

```
isequal({a,b,c,d}, {'a', '0', '10', '20'})
```

This will return `true` iff `a` has the value `'a'` and so on.

EDIT

To perform multiple *assignments*, you can use DEAL

```
[a,b,c,d] = deal('a', '0', '10', '20')
```

Comment: I think we have a very strong language barrier in effect. By `compare` she really means `assign`.