# Comparison of array with different types in Matlab

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to compare array with matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533761/how-to-compare-array-with-matlab)

Here's an example of what I'm looking for:

```
[a,b,c,d] = getVal(x);
```

This will give:

```
a =
    a

b=
    0

c =
    10

d =
    []
```

And I have:

```
expected = {'a','0','10',[]};
```

How could I make the comparison between `[a,b,c,d]` and expected ?
When I call only `getVal(x)`, it gives me only the first value and when I write:

```
[a,b,c,d] = getVal(x)
```

Then I got all values in the log. Why isn't this  the case when I call
`getVal(x)`?
For comparison I tried:

```
isequal([a,b,c,d], expected {1:end})
```

but it doesn't work, any idea how to solve my problem?

Comment: you could've just edited your previous question and continued there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533761/how-to-compare-array-with-matlab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to put `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` into a matrix. That would append spaces. Instead, use a cell array, just like you have for `expected`:

```
>> a='a'; b='0'; c='10'; d=[];
>> expected = {'a','0','10',[]};
>> isequaln({a,b,c,d}, expected)

ans =

     1
```

You also asked why simply calling `getVal(x)` doesn't give all the values. That is because in MATLAB, a function can (and often does) react to the number of output parameters, i.e., the number of variables on the left hand side of the assignment. Your `getVal` function returns four values if called with four output parameters; If it doesn't do anything special, then calling it with zero or one output parameter will return only the first of these values, in your example, `'a'`. If you want a cell array with all four of these values, do something like

```
[a, b, c, d] = getVal(x)
{a, b, c, d}
```

Comment: I'm using a function getVal(x) witch returns [a,b,c,d], and I want to compare this to expected

Comment: So? The comparison step is not affected by how a though d got their values. (Just to be on the safe side: “compare” means “take two things and check if they are equal.”)

Comment: in your proposed solution you are construncting two expected values whereas I want to compare expected to the actual value returned by function

Comment: Just replace the first line by the first line of your code above. It doesn't matter where the values come from.

Comment: I've tried : [a, b, c, d] = getVal(x) ; then isequal({a,b,c,d}, expected) and this seems working. but I can't do directly : {a, b, c, d} = getVal(x)? Thanks Christopher

Comment: No, you can't. The left hand side of an assignment cannot be a cell array of variables. (In case you plan to compare doubles, check out the difference between `isequal` and `isequaln`.)