# How to do multiple assignment of vectors in MATLAB?

Tags: function, matlab, vector, arguments, formula

Please I want a help from you . 
I have 3 vectors with values `x=[2,4] y=[5,6] z=[2,1]` 
I want to say that `[u,v,c]=[x,y,z]`
and I want to use (obligatory) this formula : 
[u,v,c]=???
I can say for example : `a=[x,y,z]` 
but this is not allowed for our assignment .
I tried many time but Matlab said (too many arguments).
please help me.

Comment: what is `[u,v,w]` - does this mean that `u=x`,`v=y`, or that each of `u`,`v`,`w` should become `[x,y,z]`?

Comment: You can use `[u,v,d] = deal(a,b,c);`.

Comment: Possible duplicate ["How do I do multiple assignment in MATLAB?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337126/how-do-i-do-multiple-assignment-in-matlab).

Comment: @Tobold That question deals with scalars. The answer doesn't work for vectors.

Comment: Thanks ,every thing is good now

Comment: @TimN Yes, you're right. Similar but not exactly the same. Who downvoted this? Maybe the questions' titles should be edited to reflect their focus on scalars and vectors respectively. "how to write in the left side [u,v,c]?" isn't compelling anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `deal`, which matches up input and output lists:

```
>> [u,v,c] = deal(x,y,z)

u =
     2     4
v =
     5     6
c =
     2     1
```