# assigning multiple varables with one call to single-output MATLAB function

Tags: matlab, function, arguments, return-value

I want to take the simple example code and assign a unique `rand()` to each variable -- on one line:

```
X = rand();

Y = rand();
```

possible?

Comment: why wont you just use a vector ? `x=rand(1,2)` then `x(1)` and `x(2)` are your two variables...

Comment: agreed - that would be cleaner here. for the larger problem, i needed a lot of variables with unique descriptive names

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I do multiple assignment in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337126/how-do-i-do-multiple-assignment-in-matlab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you absolutely want it in a single line, you can do:

```
[X, Y] = deal(rand(), rand());
```

Not a big gain, though.

Comment: cool, that's the function i was looking for - thanks! (agreed, it's overkill / loses readability for this light code, but will help a great deal for my other implementations.)

Comment: @j4ke / Milo, In MATLAB version 7.0 or higher, you can achieve the same effect without `deal` using [comma-separated lists](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html). Refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2337126/1336150#2337336) of the duplicate question I've linked to.

Answer (score 1):

One line...

```
X = rand(); Y = rand();
```

... is that all you needed?