# How to manipulate and assign parts of a MATLAB field - Comma-separated list assignment

Tags: matlab, field, assign

Consider the following MATLAB struct:

```
a(1).num=1; a(2).num=2; a(3).num=3;
```

The thing I want to do is to replace some of the elements of num with the old value minus a (scalar) number. For example, I would like to subtract 1 from `a(2).num` and `a(3).num`.

I already tried different ways:

```
a(2:3).num=a(2:3).num-1;


??? Error using ==> minus Too many input arguments.
```

Next try:

```
>>a(2:3).num=[a(2:3).num]-1;

??? Insufficient outputs from right hand side to satisfy comma separated list 
expansion on left hand side. Missing [] are the most likely cause.
```

And last:

```
>> [a(2:3).num]=[a(2:3).num]-1;

??? Error using ==> minus
Too many output arguments.
```

`arrayfun` couldn´t help either.
Probably there is a quite easy answer to this question, but I couldn´t find any.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337126/how-do-i-do-multiple-assignment-in-matlab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest is a two-line solution:

```
C = num2cell([a(2:3).num]-1);
[a(2:3).num] = C{:}
```

Nicest is to have a function like `deal`, but with a function applied to each argument:

```
function varargout = fcnDeal(varargin)

    %// (Copied from MATLAB's deal()

    if nargin==1,
        varargout = varargin(ones(1,nargout));
    else
        if nargout ~= nargin-1
            error('fcnDeal:narginNargoutMismatch',...
                'The number of outputs should match the number of inputs.')
        end
        %//...Except this part
        varargout = cellfun(varargin{1}, varargin(2:end), 'UniformOutput', false);
    end

end
```

Then what you want to do is just a matter of

```
[a(2:3).num] = fcnDeal(@(x)x-1, a(2:3).num)
```

Comment: Thank you for this elegant solution. I chose the first one, since i understand better what it does.

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate them in the loop

```
index = [1,2] 
for i = index
a(i).num = a(i).num - 1;
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer as well. I prefer the way without the loop as Rody suggested.

Comment: @Paul: In akfaz' defense: if you type `edit num2cell`, you'll see that that is essentially a loop as well. Akfaz' solution might actually be slightly faster, since there is no function call, and error checking etc. is skipped.

Comment: Thats interesting to know. Thanks!